# Azure AD B2C embedded password reset process

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to do the embedded password reset flow documented here:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset

It appears that this only works when using the content definitions of unifiedssp contract and not the selfasserted versions which is what I am currently using.  I would be able to use the unifiedssp version but i need to be able to add an additional input claim on the UI to be displayed to the user which the unifiedssp doesn't appear to support  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#output-claims-sign-up-or-sign-in-page).  Is there a way to do this embedded password reset flow using the self asserted content definition or on the unifedssp have the ability to show an additional input text box?

```
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.2</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

I would expect to be able to do the embedded password reset flow documented in this article https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset using a selfAsserted content definition version